# Adding foreign key to column in mysql does not create one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I already have two tables (book and author). Both tables are already filled. In book table is column author_id pointing to author. There is no foreign key constraint. I wanted to add foreign key constrain using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE Book
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_book$author
FOREIGN KEY (author_id)
REFERENCES Author(author_id)
```

This returns me this result:
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

I looked into the constraint table of information schema DB but I did not see there any new record about foreign key. Therefore I guess nothing happened.

Table book has more than 60000 records.

Is there any constraint that I cannot alter table with "foreign key" in tables with more than xyzvw records? 
What am I doing wrong?

I am running MySQL version 5.6.17.

Comment: What table engine do you use, innodb or myisam (or something special)? Have you checked the book table's create table statement (show create table ...) if it's updated?

Comment: It would be a good idea to show the schema for the 2 tables in question

Comment: I use myisam. This engine does not support foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below points-

1. Table engine should be innodb.
2. column properties (data type, length etc.) should be same for link column in parent/child both tables.
3. referenced column should be indexed in parent table.
4. If tables already have data then each child value in referenced column should exist in parent table also.

If all above points are fine, then share error details thrown by mysql.

Comment: Thanks for answer Zafir. I gound out that I use myisam and this engine does not support foreign keys. Therefore it does not work.